# SQL Server stored procedure does not return data to the class but works fine in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to retrieve data from this SQL Server stored procedure from a vb class and on the class:

```
Dim GetDailySalesAmateurRptOrderItems_DataArray(,) As String = 
oDAL.GetDailySalesAmateurRptOrderItems("2014-04-17", "2014-04-20")
```

Even though there is enough data in the database it returns nothing to the array... any idea what is causing this problem?

```
USE [QUICKFIX_COLOR_LAB_POS]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[GetDailySalesAmateurRptOrderItems] 
   @FromDate Datetime, @ToDate Datetime
as
   SELECT        
       ITEMS.ItemID, ITEMS.ItemName, ORDER_ITEMSET.Qty, 
       ORDER_ITEMSET.SoldPrice, ORDERS.OrderTimestamp
   FROM            
       ORDERS 
   INNER JOIN
       ORDER_ITEMSET ON ORDERS.OrderID = ORDER_ITEMSET.OrderID 
   INNER JOIN
       CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS ON ORDERS.CustomerID = CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS.CUSTOMER_ID 
   CROSS JOIN
       ITEMS
   WHERE        
       (CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS.CUSTOMER_CATEGORY = 'Amateur') 
       AND (ORDERS.OrderTimestamp BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @FromDate, 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, @ToDate, 102))
   ORDER BY 
       ITEMS.ItemID
```

VB function

```
    Function GetDailySalesAmateurRptOrderItems(DateFrom As String, ByVal DateTo As String)
        Try
            Dim DateFrom_Date As DateTime = DateFrom
            Dim DateTo_Date As DateTime = DateTo
            Dim output(,) As String
            Dim counter As Integer
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("GetDailySalesAmateurRptOrderItems", DBconn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FromDate", DateFrom_Date)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ToDate", DateTo_Date)
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader
            DBconn.Open()
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            While reader.Read()
                counter = counter + 1
            End While
            ReDim output(counter - 1, 0 To 4)
            counter = 0
            reader.Close()
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            While reader.Read()
                output(counter, 0) = reader(0)
                output(counter, 1) = reader(1)
                output(counter, 2) = reader(2)
                output(counter, 3) = reader(3)
                output(counter, 4) = reader(4)
                counter = counter + 1
            End While
            DBconn.Close()
            Return output
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ex.Message
        End Try
    End Function
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of DateFrom_Date and DateTo_Date? Also I recommend you to use a SQL Server Profiler, then you can see exactly what is going on

Comment: exec GetDailySalesAmateurRptOrderItems @FromDate='2014-04-17 00:00:00',@ToDate='2014-04-20 00:00:00'

Comment: Have you run the query directly so as to know exactly the expected results the program should return?

Comment: I ran it and here is the result http://s1.postimg.org/4zi4d3ysv/screenshot.png

Comment: You are executing the query twice, which is not good.  I presume that the purpose of executing the query the first time is to get the number of rows so that you can create the array.  Instead, create a class to represent one row of your result set, and then use an List of that class to hold your results.  You can return an array from that.  This way you can avoid executing your query twice.